# How do I permanently trust an SSL cert?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3

We host some page images on an AWS bucket. In fact, we've got a couple of buckets (ie: dev, stage, live).

When viewing the stage site over HTTPS, images from the bucket aren't displayed. An example URL might be:

https://stage-assets.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/amusing-cat.gif

When I open this URL in a tab of its own, I get the Chrome SSL Error, telling me that

"You attempted to reach **liveassets.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com**, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as ***.s3.amazonaws.com.**"

I can click the "Proceed Anyway" button and, until I next quit Chrome, the exception is added and I can see all the page images.

Next time I open Chrome, the issue reappears.

How can I tell Chrome|Firefox|IE** to permanently use the *.s3.amazonaws.com cert for these domains?

** A solution that will work in all browsers would be great - but something that works at all is all I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (wildcard) certificate will only cover anything.s3.amazonaws.com, because the certificate will only cover the second subdomain.

What you are trying to secure (stage-assets.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com or liveassets.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com) is on the fourth subdomain. what you will need for this is something like *.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com